# Android (auto accept)

Tags: android

While connecting to a peer using WiFi Direct, user's permission is required. I know that connection can't be made without the user giving the permission. So I would like a way to ask the user for permission once at the first start of the application.
Thanks for the help

Comment: what is your target version? it is different for pre `Android Marshmallow` and post `Android Marshmallow` devices.

Comment: For post `Android Marshmallow` device see https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html